# My Unity Project gives errors when building

Tags: unity-game-engine, build, unity-webgl

I have some problems when i want to build my unity 2D project with webGL. I am a programming starter, and for my school i made a final project, i choose to make a game. Now i have this errors and i have to present this game in a public presentation. Can someone help me? [Third Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqoMb.png)[Fourth Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkWMH.png)[Code 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6fQE.png)[Code 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXvFF.png)[Code 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4dIP.png)[Code 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29lZZ.png)[Code 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDoou.png)[Code 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXePY.png)

Comment: The first error says cannot find directory - start there

Comment: Please [edit] the question and make it readable. Don't post links to images, use formatted text for the code and the error message. Focus on a single problem.

Answer (score 0):

You try to load a file with a bad path.

Look at all your files path and check them to see if there are corrects.

Comment: can you explain how and where i check the file paths? Sorry im a beginner.

Comment: Somewhere in your code you are loading a file, and to load it you have to give a File path, the path to where the file is located. I don't know where is it because i don't know your code. Try to edit your question and paste the code where you load the file in order to locate the problem and help you

Comment: Thank you. I now added the Code, so you can have a look, because i did not have found any file i loaded in the code.